# How to flip two digits and double it in a sentence?(c# array)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

i need to know how to flip two digits from a sentence and double the flipped digits in a sentence.(c# array)

eg: hi! I'm 51 years old.---> to --> hi! I'm 30 years old (51-->15 --> 15*2=30)

i cant think of any code to do it. please help me!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). If you can't think of any code and can't be bothered to use proper capitalization, you may consider https://www.upwork.com/

Comment: You may want to split the task into smaller ones and think about then one by one. Like: 1. find the 2-digit number in the sentence, 2. flip digits and multiply by two, 3. replace the original number by the new one in the sentence.

Comment: is the number always two-digit integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You must first identify the number in the sentence using regular expressions (`Regex.Match(s, @"\d+"`))
- Then reverse the number, which is done with the `Reverse function`
- Then `replace` the desired number with the `doubled and reversed number`:

  ```
    string s = "hi! I'm 51 years old";
    var number = int.Parse(Regex.Match(s, @"\d+").Value);
    string s2 = s.Replace(number, (int.Parse(Reverse(number)) * 2).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(s2); //hi! I'm 30 years old


    public string Reverse(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
  ```